# Nabla/del of $(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I want to take nabla, w.r.t. $\mathbf x$, of the function 
$$
f(\mathbf x)=\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2 \tag 1
$$

Is the following correct:
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf x)
&=
\nabla\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2\bigg)\\
&=
\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\nabla(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\\
&=
-\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\tag 2
\\
&\dots \text{Multiply?}
\end{align}

Or must I expand the parenthesis first:
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf x)
&=
\nabla\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m
(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2
\bigg)\\
&=
\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m
(
y_i^2-y_i\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)y_i +\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
)\\
&=
\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m
(
y_i^2-2y_i\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i) +\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
)\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^m
(
-2y_i\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i) +\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
) \tag 3\\
&\dots\text{Stuck here}
\end{align}

Comment: Are you using cartesian coordinate system? What is $\hat y$ and $y_i$?

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same,

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf x)
&=
\nabla\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2\bigg)\\
&=
\color{blue}{2}\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\\
&=
\color{blue}{2}\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\nabla(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\\
&=
-\color{red}{2\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))}\tag 1
\end{align}

If you expand instead

\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf x)
&=
\nabla\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^m
(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))^2
\bigg)\\
&=
\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m
(
y_i^2-y_i\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)y_i +\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
)\\
&=
\nabla\sum_{i=1}^m
(
y_i^2-2y_i\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i) +\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
)\\
&=
\sum_{i=1}^m
(
-2y_i\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i) +\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)^2
) \\
&= 
\sum_{i=1}^m
(
-2y_i\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i) +2 \hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i)
) \\
&=
\color{red}{-2\sum_{i=1}^m(y_i-\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))\nabla\hat y(\mathbf x,t_i))}\tag 2
\end{align}

$(1) \equiv (2)$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of diving into indices, you can handle this problem using vector/matrix notation.

For convenience, define the vector/matrix variables 
$$\eqalign{
w=({\hat y}-y),\,\,\,\,
J = \frac{\partial{\hat y}}{\partial x} = \nabla{\hat y}
}$$
Write the function in terms of these, and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
f &= w^Tw \cr
df &= 2w^Tdw = 2w^Td{\hat y} = 2w^TJ\,dx = 2(J^Tw)^Tdx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &=2J^Tw = 2\,(\nabla{\hat y})^T({\hat y}-y)
}$$